# Windows Batch: automated Dataimport from USB-Drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, import, copy

I wrote a script that should detect when an USB-Devices is mounted (I:) and when the text database on the harddrive is not empty it should copy the data in an new generated textfile on drive C: with an unique name. After the operationit should delete the database and create an new empty one.

I got two problems I am not able to resolve. The first file contains all datas as intended. After that the database is deleted and new created. But in the second run the size is still the old one so all operations are repeated. Altough the database is empty.

Second Problem is, the if condition seems not to work. The brakets are always executed.

```
@echo off

:loop
if exist I:\ (
    :GETTEMPNAME
        set TMPFILE=UL%DATE%_%RANDOM%
        if exist "%TMPFILE%" GOTO :GETTEMPNAME
    echo %TMPFILE%


    echo success
    I:
    set size=0
    call :filesize "I:\database.txt"
    echo file size is %size%

    set sizelimit = 6
    if "%size%" GTR "%sizelimit%" (
        echo greater
        C:
        cd C:\SaveData
        type NUL > %TMPFILE%.txt
        echo S:OK; >> %TMPFILE%.txt

        echo accessing data
        I:


        for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (database.txt) do (
        C:
        echo %%A >> %TMPFILE%.txt
        I:
        )
        C:
        echo E:OK >> %TMPFILE%.txt
        I:
        del "database.txt"
        type NUL > database.txt

    )


    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 40 > 0



) else (
    echo waiting for data
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 40 > NUL
)

goto loop

:: set filesize of 1st argument in %size% variable, and return
:filesize
  set size=%~z1
```

Here is the log from the cmd:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Where is your `UL%DATE%_%RANDOM%.txt` file supposed to be written to, "C:\SaveData\" or "C:\"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your script and assumed `C:\SaveData\` as the intended location for your output text file, *please change it if my assumption was incorrect*.

```bat
@Echo Off

:Loop
If Not Exist I:\ (Echo=Waiting for data ...
    Timeout 40 /NoBreak>Nul
    GoTo Loop)
CD /D I:\
If Not Exist "database.txt" Exit/B
Echo=Success
SetLocal

:GetTempName
Set "TmpFile=C:\SaveData\UL%DATE%_%RANDOM%.txt"
If Exist "%TmpFile%" GoTo GetTempName
Set "SizeLimit=6"
For %%A In ("database.txt") Do Set "Size=%%~zA"
Echo=File size is %Size%
If %Size% Gtr %SizeLimit% (Echo=Greater
    Echo=S:OK;>"%TmpFile%"
    Echo=Accessing data ...
    Type "database.txt">>"%TmpFile%"
    Echo=E:OK>>"%TmpFile%"
    Type Nul>"database.txt")
EndLocal
Timeout 40 /NoBreak>Nul
GoTo Loop
```